# How to express "Again?"

Tags: learning

How would one state "Again?" like an expression of surprise? Do we still use また?

Answer (score 7):

We say:

「また？」

「またあ？」

「またなの？」

「またですか？」

「えっ、また？」

「うそっ、またあ？」

「また + Verb + の？」 as in 「また[来]{き}たの？」

「また + Verb + んですか？」 as in 「また[食]{た}べるんですか？」

etc.

EDIT: Adding a slangy version.

「またっすか？」

Answer (score 3):

Another slangy version. 
またかよ！